# Geometric Interpretation of eigen values to matrix definitness

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

When finding the second-order conditions of a function we need to see if the Hessian matrix, $H$,  is positive definite. This will determine whether the point is a local maximum, minima, or saddlepoint.

We do so by finding the determinant and test $|H| >,<,=0$. The determinant is also the product of eigenvalues $\prod\lambda$. How do eigenvalues relate to the definiteness of a matrix?

Geometrically, in $\mathbb{R}^3$,  I know that determinants find the volume of a parallelepiped formed by the column vectors of a matrix. The $\Lambda$ matrix is a parallelepiped transformed into a cube so that multiplying the diagonals entries (dimension of the cube) gives the volume/determinant.

Why does the determinant of a Hessian matrix help determine the definiteness of a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

The determinant on its own does not tell us about the definiteness of a matrix, but it does give us some information. $H$ is positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are positive. The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. You can see that if the determinant were, for instance, zero or negative, then we would instantly know $H$ is not positive definite. But if the determinant is positive, this doesn't give us a guarantee that $H$ is positive definite.

However, we can often answer the question completely using the determinant along with other information. For instance, if $H$ is $2\times 2$, then it is positive definite if and only if both the determinant and trace are positive.

Comment: [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) gives a condition equivalent to positive-definiteness purely in terms of (multiple) determinants.